# Python: When do two variables point at the same object in memory?

Tags: python, pointers

Here is an example:

```
l = [1, 5, 9, 3]
h = l

h[0], h[2] = h[2], h[0]

print(h) # [9, 5, 1, 3]
print(l) # [9, 5, 1, 3]

h = h*2
print(h) # [9, 5, 1, 3, 9, 5, 1, 3]
print(l) # [9, 5, 1, 3]
```

My understanding was that calling setting `h = l` would simply point `h` at the same item in memory that `l` was pointing at. So why is it that in the last 3 lines, `h` and `l` don't give the same results?

Comment: You change what `h` points to when you assign to `h` again.

Comment: It depends on whether the value of the variable is mutable. Lists are mutable, Integers aren't.

Comment: Setting `h = l` does point `h` at `l`.  But then setting `h = h*2` points `h` to something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assignment does make **h** point to the same item as **l**.  However, it does not permanently weld the two.  When you change **h** with **h = h * 2**, you tell Python to build a doubled version elsewhere in memory, and then make **h** point to the doubled version.  You haven't given any instructions to change **l**; that still points to the original item.

Answer (score 9):

That's quite simple to check, run this simple test:

```
l = [1, 5, 9, 3]
h = l

h[0], h[2] = h[2], h[0]

print(h)  # [9, 5, 1, 3]
print(l)  # [9, 5, 1, 3]

print id(h), id(l)
h = h * 2
print id(h), id(l)

print(h)  # [9, 5, 1, 3, 9, 5, 1, 3]
print(l)  # [9, 5, 1, 3]
```

As you can see because of the line `h = h * 2`, the h's id has been changed

Why is this? When you're using `*` operator it creates a new list (new memory space). In your case this new list is being assigned to the old h reference, that's why you can see the id is different after `h = h * 2`

If you want to know more about this subject, make sure you look at [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) link.

Answer (score 4):

`h = h * 2` assigns `h` to a new list object.

You probably want to modify `h` *in-place*:

```
h *= 2
print(h) # [9, 5, 1, 3, 9, 5, 1, 3]
print(l) # [9, 5, 1, 3, 9, 5, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Short and sweet... +1 `h += h * 2` would work too. :)

Comment: @l'L'l That works, but won't it triple rather than double? You meant `h += h`?

Comment: Yeah thanks for the correction, that's what I meant, my phone somehow left the * 2... on there.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you assign to a variable, its identity (memory address) generally changes - the only reason why it wouldn't change is that you happened to assign it the value that it already held.  So, your statement `h = h * 2` caused h to become an entirely new object - one whose value happened to be based on the previous value of h, but that's not actually relevant to its identity.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky, but when you multiply a list, you are creating a new list.

```
l = [1, 5, 9, 3]
h = l
```

'l' and 'h' are now referring to the same list in memory.

```
h[0], h[2] = h[2], h[0]

print(h)  # [9, 5, 1, 3]
print(l)  # [9, 5, 1, 3]
```

You swapped the values in `h`, so the values are changed in `l`.  This makes sense when you think about them as different names for *the same object*

```
h = h * 2

print(h)  # [9, 5, 1, 3, 9, 5, 1, 3]
print(l)  # [9, 5, 1, 3]
```

When multiplying `h * 2`, you are creating a *new list*, so now only `l` will be the original list object.

```
>>> l = [1, 5, 9, 3]
>>> h = l
>>> id(h) == id(l)
True
>>> id(h)
139753623282464
>>> h = h * 2
>>> id(h) == id(l)
False
>>> id(h)
139753624022264
```

See how the `id` of `h` changes after the multiplication?  The `*` operator creates a new list, unlike other list operation, such as `append()` which alter the current list.

```
>>> h.append(1000)
>>> id(h)
139753623282464    # same as above!
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
print np.may_share_memory(l,k)
```

helps in confirming if two variables l and k share the same memory

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking up how to test if two variables *actually* point to the same memory address, use the `is` keyword.

In the case of a python list, `is` also applies. Alternatively for lists, an element-wise (deep) comparison can be performed using the `==` operator.

Here's an example:

```
>>> j = [1, 2, 3, 456]
>>> i = j
>>> i == j  # element-wise comparison
True
>>> j is i  # both variables point to the same memory address
True
>>> i is j
True
```

Now we assign i to another list **even though it has the same elements**

```
>>> j = [1, 2, 3, 456]
>>> i = [1, 2, 3, 456]
>>> i == j  # element-wise comparison
True
>>> i is j  # do they point to the same memory address?
False
```